# iOS compile error: no visible @interface for 'CDVCommandDelegateImpl' declares the selector 'execute:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cordova

After upgrading to latest Cordova version (**3.6.3**) i get this error when running the `cordova build ios` command.

**The error:**

```
/Volumes/local.uhmuhm.net/projectxxx/htdocs/phonegap/src/Projectxxx/platforms/ios/Projectxxx/Classes/MainViewController.m:154:19: error: no visible @interface for 'CDVCommandDelegateImpl' declares the selector 'execute:' return [super execute:command];
```

**Other info:**

- Installed platforms: android 3.6.3, **ios 3.6.3**
- I'm on last xcode version (6.0.1)
- Everything started after upgrading Cordova to 3.6.3 (i was running 3.4.1 before that)

**Any idea on how to solve this?**

[image]

Comment: Downagraded to Cordova 3.5 and everything is working again.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Building on what Nazar said, the only difference of significance when creating a new app and comparing an existing `platforms/ios/Classes` folder was removing the `execute` method from `MainViewController.m`.

[image: file diff]

This clears up the build error for me.

Comment: Thanks! I really didn't have the stomach to remove/recreate my ios platform!

Comment: Doing the remove / add steps above removed some things I had committed to Git so going this route was a better choice for me to fix this issue. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: This worked for me too, though I don't like having to modify these files which aren't directly part of my project. Anyone have any neat solutions for including these modified files in version control, whilst also allowing for cordova to do its thing?

Comment: That solved the error, but now I get a load of 'Apple Mach-O Linker' Errors. Cordova platform update has simply never worked.

Answer (score 30):

I've fixed the same problem with

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios
```

Comment: Great! Gonna give it a try.

Comment: This will delete any source files you have in that directory, just so you know

Comment: You should put all source into www and merge folders on root directory which won't be removed.

Comment: This is nothing but removing the IOS project and recreating as a new one.. Beware this helps only for the user who are using common codebase..

Comment: This is unnecessary and destructive. SKFox's solution below is the one that should be accepted because that's all that is required to get it too work and you won't lose objective C code that is part of your existing iOS project.

Comment: I keep seeing "remove and add the platform" as the solution to Cordova problems. This is a pain because for a start we have to restore all the icons and so on. `cordova platform update ios` is evidently broken, or not smart enough.

Comment: Cordova guys suck. They release broken upgrades every single version!

Answer (score 12):

Run `cordova create` with new cordova version to create new project then copy `AppDelegate` and `MainViewController` over files in your "old" project. After that the error is gone.

Answer (score 2):

I've had same problem today. I tracked down that CordovaLib/Classes/CDVCommandDelegateImpl.m file doesn't have this:

```
- (BOOL)execute:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    return [_commandQueue execute:command];
}
```

as it was in same file in the latest Cordova 3.5.0.
So I've added this snippet and also proper declaration in CDVCommandDelegateImpl.h file:

```
- (BOOL)execute:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
```

And now my app is running! Not sure if this is good solution, but if it works then it's good enough :)